# How can I find hive jobs from odbc queries?

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, impala

how are u doing? I hope you're fine!

I used to execute hive queries with python, using pyodbc module with Impala Driver.

Is there a way, to visualize job logs in hadoop cluster manager, in order to obtain more details about job execution?

I can't find these queries, does it generates visible jobs in cluster manager?

Thanks from Brazil!

Comment: why don't just open the yarn manager?? `8088` port.

Comment: there you'll see all the executions. or do you want to see the current mr in execution?

Comment: Kenry, my problem is that I couldn't find that jobs in manager. So, it really generates jobs? That's the question...

Comment: yeah, of course, I mean if you're using `yarn` to schedule jobs, every time a mr job is submitted it is going to register it in the admin panel, so you can go to `localhost:8088` and see the execution. Remember that hive jobs are basically mr jobs, so for the cluster is the same.

Comment: @KenrySanchez can I see queries submited by pyodbc?

Comment: well, you are going to see the mr job executed by the pyodbc query but not the query itself.

Comment: Is there some way to search by query text?

Comment: well, I don't know. another solution could be search by the job id execution generated by the query text.

Comment: ahh another thing, I almost forget it. if you want to use this way you've to init the historyserver deamon as well as the schedulerHandler service. if not, you are not going to saw the job submitted.

Comment: i hope it will use to you